# Simplify the product of two sums

Tags: summation, products

How can I simplify the following product of two sums:

$$
\biggl(\, \sum ^{n}_{k=0}a_{k}\biggr) \biggl(\, \sum ^{n}_{k=0}\dfrac {1}{a_{k}}\biggr) 
$$

Comment: Are $a_0, a_1,...,a_k$ consecutive integers, by chance?

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry for the forgetting!

Comment: No problem. Is $a_0=1$?

Comment: There isn't a lot you can do, since arithmetic series are easily summed, while there is no simple expression for [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: If it helps, you can use $AM \geq GM$ to bound the product from below by $n^2$.

Comment: I wonder why his account was deleted?

Comment: it must be positive real numbers

Comment: See [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).